# How to verify deb package signature?

Tags: gpg, deb

I download a deb package from GitHub, specifically [gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/releases/tag/v2.0.785)

How can I tell if the package is signed and how can I verify the signature?

---

I tried some dpkg commands. These seem to show the package is signed with a key BE1229CF.

```
> dpkg-sig --verify gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb
Processing gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb...
UNKNOWNSIG _gpgorigin BE1229CF
```

```
> debsig-verify gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb 
debsig: Could not open Origin directory /etc/debsig/policies/EB3E94ADBE1229CF: No such file or directory
```

This key is published at  https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

```
> gpg microsoft.asc 
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
pub   rsa2048 2015-10-28 [SC]
      BC528686B50D79E339D3721CEB3E94ADBE1229CF
uid           Microsoft (Release signing) <gpgsecurity@microsoft.com>
```

but I'm still not sure how to verify

---

Aha after `gpg --import microsoft.asc` it recognises the key, but it still fails BADSIG.

```
> dpkg-sig --verify gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb
Processing gcm-linux_amd64.2.0.785.deb...
BADSIG _gpgorigin
```

Comment: When GPG fingerprints are abbreviated, you use the last X characters.  `BC528686B50D79E339D3721CEB3E94ADBE1229CF` can be abbreviated to its last 16 characters (`EB3E94ADBE1229CF`) or its last 8 characters (`BE1229CF`).  That key you are using probably matches.  You just need to import it as a public key.

Comment: I imagine you posted [this issue](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/issues/809), right? I suspect you’ll get a better answer there than here ;-).